# UISwitch doesn't maintain its value when leaving the view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiswitch

If I were to switch my `UISwitch` controller to "off" and leave the view controller and come back to the view controller it will show the `UISwitch` is "on" (default value) instead of "off". How do I save the value of the UISwitch controller when switching from/to view controllers?

```
- (void)controlsEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    self.onandoffSwitch.enabled = enabled;   
    if (enabled)
    {
        NSLog(@"ON");    
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"OFF");     
    }
}
```

Comment: I answered a similar question and included a sample project on Github you can reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13666090/1176156

Comment: Usually when you post a question, you should include your code you're working with. What you posted doesn't compile..

Comment: It's probably because when you "come back to the view controller", you're actually coming back to a new instance. You need to include some detail about how you are moving between the 2 controllers.

Comment: Here is the accepted Answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782489/how-to-keep-user-set-values-to-uiswitch

Answer (score 5):

You need to persist the setting in some way. Here's an example using `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:yourSwitch.on forKey:@"switchValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And read it when you load the view hierarchy again:

```
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL state = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switchValue"];
```

Comment: You don't need to do this if the controller itself is persisting -- the switch will maintain its state if you go back to the same controller you originally came from.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for the switch state not persisting, is that you're creating a new instance (with the default switch state) of the controller, rather than going back to the one you originally came from. If you're using segues, they always instantiate new controllers when you perform them (except for unwind segues). Also modally presented controllers are deallocated when you dismiss them, unless you keep a strong reference to them somewhere. So, how to make the switch maintain its state depends on whether you want to go back to the same instance, and how you go about doing that.